# Get all status's from JIRA webservice

Tags: rest, jira

Is there a way to get all status types from the JIRA webservice, either through the api or through a JQL request?  (The issue status is the field that is mapped to the swimlanes when the board is set up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whith JIRA REST API you can :
rest/api/2/status
or for each project :
rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}/statuses

see the online rest api browser : it's a wonderful tool :
https://jira.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/api-2-status

Comment: I thought that wasn't working properly because it sent me back more statuses than I had lanes, but I think that maybe the guy that set up the board mapped more than one status to some of the lanes and that would explain why there are so many.  I'm guessing there's not a way to get a single status for each lane.  Without that it is going to make this app significantly more complicated.

Comment: "Lanes" : You're using GrennHopper/Agile plugin? Hannies'answer is for you. Jira configuration is very open, and available status depends on the workflows you configured, and you may bind more than one status to each lane.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, to see what's in a project's swimlanes for a JIRA agile board you make a request like this: https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/xboard/work/allData.json?rapidViewId=560 and it will return the relevant information.

Each board has a rapidViewId so you'll have to query for that yourself using a request like this: /rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapidview.

All this stuff can be found here: https://jira.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/greenhopper-1-0-rapidview

This is for future reference so that people don't have to go through the same trouble I did when trying to figure this out. Hope it helps!